# Draw panel in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsbezierpath

I have a NSBezierPath, in the shape of a menubar panel.

[image]

I'd like to make a header now.
Like [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/255396-mite-Client-for-Mac) one for example.
But only like 30 pixels from the top.

I can't figure out how I should only get the top part of the NSBezierPath.
This is my first question.
How can I cut off a piece of the NSBezierPath, or how can I make a Union of the NSBezierPath.

Then I want to add a gradient like in the example.
The gradient is clear, but how can I add the glow at the top of it?
I have added a shadow in another app back then, but it seemed a little dirty.

[image]

So how can I make a shadow at the top of the NSBezierPath, like in the provided example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com), which did a pretty good job for me.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the 'light' edge at the top of the element you can just draw (i.e. [`:fill`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/fill)) the `NSBezierPath` with a vertical offset of e.g. -1 points with a brighter color. Then draw the shape (at y=+1 points) on top of that.

Not sure what you mean by making the header and cutting of bits..

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
With the second question I mean, that I want to cut the bottom off the NSBezierPath. The first picture shows the whole bezier path. I would like to cut the bottom off, so I only have a slice of the top, like here: http://dribbble.com/shots/255396-mite-Client-for-Mac